# Python/PySide6: editor error when resetting tableView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside6

In my current project I'm facing the problem, that an error occurs, when editing a cell in a TableView.

```
QAbstractItemView::closeEditor called with an editor that does not belong to this view
QAbstractItemView::commitData called with an editor that does not belong to this view
QAbstractItemView::closeEditor called with an editor that does not belong to this view
```

I have a modified QAbstractTableModel to have control over the behavior and I'm working with DataFrames as table data.

I want the following: after changing a cell, I want my main thread to register that (...dataChanged.emit...) and trigger a function that reads and modifies the data from the table model and update the table model with the modified data:

```
def handle_tableView_changed(self, index):
    df = self.tableView_model.table_data.copy()
    ### DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA AND FEED IT BACK TO TABLEVIEW
    self.tableView_model.setTableData(df)
```

This is why I trigger that process from within the table model (dataChanged.emit). In combination with the update method within the model:

```
def setTableData(self, df):
    self.beginResetModel()
    self.table_data = df
    self.endResetModel()
```

the error occurs. I think it has something to do with a circular issue.
If I call setTableData from outside the class, there is no error.

Does anyone have an idea?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QMainWindow,
    QTableView,
    QTreeView,
    QWidget,
)


class CustomTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, table_data=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(CustomTableModel, self).__init__()
        self.table_data = table_data
        self.parent = parent

    def setTableData(self, df):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.table_data = df
        self.endResetModel()

    def data(self, index, role):
        value = self.table_data.iat[index.row(), index.column()]
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            return value

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.table_data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.EditRole])
            return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.table_data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self.table_data.shape[1]


class SimpleGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Simple PySide6 GUI")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create a QTreeView on the left
        self.tree_view = QTreeView()
        self.tree_view.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.tree_view.setRootIsDecorated(True)

        # Create a QFileSystemModel to populate the QTreeView
        self.treeView_model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tree_view.setModel(self.treeView_model)
        self.init_treeView()
        self.tree_view.clicked.connect(self.treeView_clicked)

        # Create a QTableView on the right
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.tableView_model = CustomTableModel(parent=self)

        # COMMENT THESE LINES FOR QSORTFILTERPROXY BYPASS
        self.table_view.setModel(self.tableView_model)
        self.tableView_model.dataChanged.connect(self.handle_tableView_changed)

        self.table_view_data_dict = {
            "item1": ["1_1", "1_2", "1_3"],
            "item2": ["2_1", "2_2", "2_3"],
            "item3": ["3_1", "3_2", "3_3"],
        }

        # Create a vertical layout for the main window
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Add the treeView to the layout
        main_layout.addWidget(self.tree_view)

        # Add the tableView to the layout
        main_layout.addWidget(self.table_view)

        # Create a central widget and set the main layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Set the central widget for the main window
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def init_treeView(self):
        parent = self.treeView_model.invisibleRootItem()
        data = [
            "item1",
            "item2",
            "item3",
        ]
        for element in data:
            child = QStandardItem(element)
            parent.appendRow(child)

    def treeView_clicked(self, index):
        self.clicked_treeView_item = self.treeView_model.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        df_for_tableView = pd.DataFrame(self.table_view_data_dict[self.clicked_treeView_item]).T
        self.tableView_model.setTableData(df_for_tableView)

    def handle_tableView_changed(self, index):
        df = self.tableView_model.table_data.copy()
        ### EXTRACT DATA FROM DF FOR STYLING (QBackgroundRole), NO CHANGE IN MODEL DF
        self.tableView_model.setTableData(df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SimpleGUI()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks!
edit: corrected example

Comment: The problem may be caused by the fact that you're resetting the model while the data is still being changed, when `dataChanged` is emitted, you're directly trying to reset the model, but `setData()` has not returned yet at that point. But this is just a guess, you need to provide a valid [mre] that includes whatever you do in `handle_tableView_changed`.

Comment: It's still not a [mre]. Anyway, why not do like ```self.tableView_model.dataChanged.connect(self.handle_tableView_changed, type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)```?

Comment: Why isn't it a minimal reproducible example? Doesn't it precisely recreate the error?
I spared the `handle_tableView_changed` part, because - in my opinion - it has nothing to do with the issue:
Before resetting the model, I'm evaluating the modified DataFrame and set flags in a separate DataFrame, which then provides information to the model, if the background colors of cells have to be changed.
After that I want to trigger the model reset, so that `Qt.BackgroundRole` can be updated without triggering the model reset separately. Therefore I need the model reset linked to `dataChanged`.

Comment: If necessary, I can add that to the example. But then it wouldn't be "minimal" anymore :)

Comment: I falsely stated in the comment of my code:
`### DO SOMETHING WITH THE DATA AND FEED IT BACK TO TABLEVIEW`
I'm not changing the data in the model DataFrame, I just use it to modify the second DataFrame (which only serves information about whether to change the cell color).

Comment: You have to write like ```@relent95``` to notify a commenter like me. I have to modify your code to reproduce the problem. Check it again by yourself. Did you try my suggestion of using the ```QueuedConnection```?

Comment: @relent95: You are right... there was a mistake in my example code (I could swear I tested it before posting) :( sorry for that.
I edited my org. post with the correct example.

I did test your suggestion, it works at first glance (no error when editing a cell), but there are two issues: Firstly, the cell "loses focus" and the "marked cell" resets to index 0,0. Secondly, my code also includes ComboBox-Delegates for certain cells. When changing a ComboBox, the original error occurs.
Thank you for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: Unfortunately I still couldn't figure out the solution :(
Does anyone have another idea?